# Condición para cambiar icono según los grados de temperatura

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo 6 iconos de diferentes climas: 
, nublado, soleado,con rayos etc, lo que necesito es que dependiendo de la temperatura cambie el icono,como puedo hacer la condición en el ajax, este código va en medio de la condición `document.getElementsByClassName("img").src = "iconos/soleado.png";`, ya la temperatura esta en tiempo real, como lo puedo hacer?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>pieza clima</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="30;">

</head>
<body>

       
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                <source src="Videos/viento2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      <div id="contenido">
      <div id="content-text"></div>
      <div id="content-text2"></div>
<script>

    var _from = document.location.pathname.split('/'); // Permite obtener la ruta del archivo actual y convertirla en array separados por "/"
    _from = _from[_from.length - 1].replace('.html', '').replace('index_', ''); // filtramos el contenido del array y extraemos el nombre del archivo


     $.ajax({url: "http://digital12.xegmenta.com:3000/weather/api/"+_from,
    success: function(result){
      $("#content-text").html(result.name);
      $("#content-text2").html(result.main.temp);      
    }});
  </script>
  
  <h1 class="temperatura">ºC</h1>

  <img src="iconos/Nublado.png" class="img"/>
  <h1 class="dia"><script>
      var meses = new Array ("enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre");
      var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
      var f=new Date();
      document.write(diasSemana[f.getDay()] + ", " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()]);
      </script></h1>

<h1 class="hora"><span id="liveclock" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;"></span><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function show5(){
 if (!document.layers&&!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
 return
  var Digital=new Date()
  var hours=Digital.getHours()
  var minutes=Digital.getMinutes()
  var seconds=Digital.getSeconds()
  var dn="PM"
 if (hours<12)
 dn="AM"
 if (hours>12)
 hours=hours-12
 if (hours==0)
 hours=12
 if (minutes<=9)
  minutes="0"+minutes
  if (seconds<=9)
  seconds="0"+seconds
 //change font size here to your desire
 myclock="<font size='10' face='Arial' ><b><font size='10'></font></br>"+hours+":"+minutes+":"
  +seconds+" "+dn+"</b></font>"
 if (document.layers){
 document.layers.liveclock.document.write(myclock)
 document.layers.liveclock.document.close()
 }
 else if (document.all)
 liveclock.innerHTML=myclock
 else if (document.getElementById)
 document.getElementById("liveclock").innerHTML=myclock
 setTimeout("show5()",1000)
  }
 window.onload=show5
  </script>
</h1>

<script>
  div = document.getElementById('contenido');
  div.setAttribute("class","ocultar");
//se ejecutara despues de 2 segundos
setTimeout(mostrarTexto, 2000);
//se ejecutara despues de 9 segundos
setTimeout(OcultarTexto, 9000);
function mostrarTexto(){
  div = document.getElementById('contenido');
  div.setAttribute("class","overlay");
}
function OcultarTexto(){
div = document.getElementById('contenido');
div.setAttribute("class","ocultar");
}//end function OcultarTexto
</script>
        
        
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos podrías hacer algo así:

```js
var ruta_diaSoleado = "https://previews.123rf.com/images/grkistock/grkistock1401/grkistock140100112/25272390-d%C3%ADa-soleado-en-la-pradera-ilustraci%C3%B3n-del-vector-.jpg";
var ruta_diaLluvia ="https://previews.123rf.com/images/mccjeff/mccjeff1711/mccjeff171100047/89866275-triste-d%C3%ADa-lluvioso.jpg";
var ruta_diaNublado = "http://www.clubcientificobezmiliana.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/IMG_13400.jpg";
var temperatura = 10;
var temperatura2 = 20;
imagen = document.getElementById('imagen_temperatura');
if(temperatura == 10){
 imagen.setAttribute('src',ruta_diaSoleado);
}
var delayInMilliseconds = 2000; //retraso de 2 segundos
setTimeout(function() {
  if(temperatura2==20){
  imagen.setAttribute('src',ruta_diaLluvia);
  }
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

```html
<img src="" alt="TEMPERATURA" id="imagen_temperatura" width="100" heigth="100">
```

Si te fijas tengo declarado previamente las rutas de las imágenes a usar para los distintos climas o tiempos, mediante un if valido la temperatura en este caso es algo básico pero deberías validar si entre en cierto rango de temperatura muestras la ruta de una image u otra, para ello uso setAttribute que reemplaza o establece ese atributo a la imagen mediante JavaScript, espero te sirva.

También he usado un setTimeout que establece o define un retraso para que se pueda notar el cambio en las imágenes eso es opcional en tu lógica, suerte!

[Documentacion setAttribute JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Comment: Todo va dentro del AJAX? como puedo cambiar el rango así? `imagen = document.getElementById('imagen_temperatura');
if(temperatura == 10 ==20){
 imagen.setAttribute('src',ruta_diaSoleado);` es usando < o = ?

Comment: exacto dentro del evento success:{.....aqui..}

Comment: la condicion depende no estoy al tanto pero supongamos es soleado si esta entre 10 a 20 grados deberias hacer algo asi if(temperatura>9 && temperatura<21){.....loque sea..}

Comment: te sugiero revisar tambien lo operadores logicos por si los necesitaras: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos}

Comment: Perfecta esta respuesta.